# Android: can local Service be killed by OS independently of the application?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I used to think that Android OS is only capable of killing the entire processes of applications, but recently I've been told that, under some conditions, OS can also kill started `Service` while keeping the `Application` intact.

So, my questions is: suppose I start (using `startService`) a local `Service` in the same process as the rest of my Android application, can this `Service` be killed by OS independently of the rest of the app (i.e. `Service` is killed and destroyed, but `Application` object remains intact)?

If such a scenario is possible, what conditions affect the probability of my `Service` being killed? Can I prevent this from happening?

Please support your answers with references and/or "prove of concept" code snippets.

Comment: Ah, I see it's exam question season

Comment: @SimonH, no, it is not. If the answer to this question is "yes", then many real world applications should take it into account (sometimes the downtime before STICKY service restarts might be unacceptable if the rest of the application is running).

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard that Android could destroy particular component of process instead of whole process and never observed this in practice. Instead Android analyzes state of your application components to decide whether your process may be killed to reclaim a memory. Check the documentation - [Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for details - documentation says nothing about destroying particular components.

Besides, there was a good article [Who lives and who dies](https://medium.com/google-developers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f#.2b56vzupg) and the author explicitly stands that **Android only kills processes, not components**, but, unfortunately, without evolving this topic.

By the way, where did you read/hear about these certain circumstances under which `Service` may be killed independently of entire process?

Answer (score -1):

`Service` is independent to `Application`. There are two ways to handle `Service` be killed

1. [`START_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)

If you return `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand()`, system will try to re-create your service after it is killed. Same intent will be passed.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

2. [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory.

Calls [`startForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) in `onStartCommand()` to start a `Service` at foreground but a notification for the status bar will be shown

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, 
        getText(R.string.ticker_text), System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: If you down vote this, please comment about the reason.

Comment: I don't think that "service is independent to application" is a valid statement in this (probably any) context. Furthermore, I did not ask how to recover service after it is killed.

Comment: @Vasiliy The second options should answer you how to lower the chance of your services being kill. Background services will be killed before foreground services. But if your service is not really important, the first option to try it later may be a better choice.

Comment: @Vasiliy Even if the `Application` is kill, the service can still be running. If the new `Application` starts the same `Service` and previous `Service` is still running, it will not call `onStartCommand()` as it considers it is the same.